# How to upload a large file on azure storage file share?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I am uploading files on azure storage file share. I followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-java-how-to-use-file-storage
It works fine, but I can not upload files larger than 2MB. What is the problem?

Spring does not show any error and on the frontend I get 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Try set `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` values in your web.config file. You could follow this doc.https://www.cnblogs.com/malaikuangren/archive/2012/09/23/2698974.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It is not an azure problem. I was converting multipart files to files before uploading. In Spring boot the default max size for multipart is 1MB so it has to be changed in application.yml. This should solve the problem:

```
servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: -1
      max-request-size: -1
```

Comment: Hi, if you solved your problem you can take your solution as the answer of this question. This will help others solve similar questions.

Comment: @BowmanZhu I can not accept my answer as the correct one for 48 hours. I still have 23h to wait.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't matter. Your solution may help more people. Thank you for your contribution to the community!